# Android Google Drive API v2 downloadUrl with access token stopped working

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

My app used to play Google Drive videos using v2's downloadUrl() + access_token

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoItem.downloadUrl() + "&access_token=" + mAccessToken), "video/avi");
startActivity(intent);
```

However, it stops working one day for no apparent reason.

I have tried using v3's webContent()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(videoItem.webContent()));
startActivity(intent);
```

But this way they will need to log in Google on the device they are viewing the video from.

Does anyone know why v2's downloadUrl() + access_token stops working?
Also why doesn't the following works? Since I want to play my videos in a third party player no in Google Drive app.

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoItem.webContent()), "video/avi");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please define stops working. did you refresh the access token after it expired?

Comment: I can no longer play videos with this link "videoItem.downloadUrl() + "&access_token=" + mAccessToken

Comment: new access token is used every time

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, `downloadUrl() + access_token` stopped working on January 1, 2020, because of [recent changes for the authorization for Google Drive API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api)

Follow the new procedure as described in the documentation, basically

> you will need to migrate your requests to authenticate using an HTTP
>   header

Comment: can you give an example of this please for V3